# sql count function with subquery

Tags: sql

here is my query

```
select narr,vocno,count(*) 
from KontenLedger 
WHERE VOCDT>'2018-07-01' 
group by narr,vocno 
having count(*)<'3'
```

actually if i wright as i given  above ,the result which calculates two fields ('narr' and 'vocno') if i remove the field ('narr') answer is correct. i need to  view the field 'narr' also without counting

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Unrelated tip: you are comparing the numeric count value against a string `'3'`. If you remove the quotes, SQL won't have to implicitly convert it.

Comment: In addition to the aforementioned by `a_horse_with_no_name` and `Richardissimo`, it's worthwhile to clarify the database used.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your database, nor having some limited sample date, nor expected output?

```
SELECT
 vocno, 
 COUNT(*) AS total,
 MAX(narr) AS max_narr
FROM KontenLedger 
WHERE vocdt > '2018-07-01' 
GROUP BY vocno 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

Comment: @nashvamuhammed Really? Okay  that's good. Thought it was going to need some database specific function. Like f.e. [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) for MS Sql Server. But I was probably just overthinking it.